# Image Segmentation Demo

Tags: java, segment

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.color.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

// 이미지유틸리티.java, 이미지분할.java
public class Image_Segmentation_Demo extends JComponent{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        String FName = "Hok1.png";
        이미지분할 Seg = new 이미지분할(FName);
        BufferedImage Source  = Seg.getImage();
//        BufferedImageOp Target = new BufferedImage(ImageIO.write("example.jpg"));
        BufferedImageOp Target = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
        BufferedImage Ref = Target.filter(Source, null);
        Seg.setSecondImage(Ref);
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.add(Seg, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setSize(f.getPreferredSize());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I want to show an image other than gray when I click it down with my mouse
I think we need to change this part to do that, but I don't know what to do

```
BufferedImageOp Target = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
```

이미지분할 Here's the extra code.
I don't know how to edit it, so I'm uploading it properly
I don't know how to fill in the insufficient explanation.It's my first time, so it's really hard to write

````
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.*;

public class 이미지분할 extends JPanel {
  private BufferedImage 이미지;
  private BufferedImage 두번째이미지;
  private int 분할x;
  
  public 이미지분할(String 경로) {
    setImage(경로); init();
  }
  
  public 이미지분할(BufferedImage 버퍼이미지) {
    setImage(버퍼이미지); init();
  }

  public void setImage(String 경로) {
    Image 버퍼이미지 = 이미지유틸리티.로드봉쇄(경로);
    이미지 = 이미지유틸리티.이미지버퍼생성(버퍼이미지);
  }

  public void setImage(BufferedImage 버퍼이미지) { 이미지 = 버퍼이미지; }

  public void setSecondImage(BufferedImage 버퍼이미지) {
    두번째이미지 = 버퍼이미지; repaint();
  }
  
  public BufferedImage getImage() { return 이미지; }
  public BufferedImage getSecondImage() { return 두번째이미지; }
  
  private void init() {
    setBackground(Color.white);
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        분할x = me.getY(); repaint();
      }
    });
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        분할x = me.getY(); repaint();
      }
    });
  }
  
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    int width = getSize().width;
    int height = getSize().height;
    
    // 명확하게 윈도우 비우기
    Rectangle clear = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    g2.setPaint(getBackground());
    g2.fill(clear);
    // 첫 번째 버퍼 이미지 절단(적절한 경우)
    if (분할x != 0 && 두번째이미지 != null) {
      Rectangle 첫번째클립 = new Rectangle(0, 분할x, width, height - 분할x);
      g2.setClip(첫번째클립);
    }
    g2.drawImage(getImage(), 0, 0, null);
    
    if (분할x == 0 || 두번째이미지 == null) return;
    
    Rectangle 두번째클립 = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, 분할x);
    g2.setClip(두번째클립);
    g2.drawImage(두번째이미지, 0, 0, null);
    
    Line2D 분할선 = new Line2D.Float(0, 분할x, width, 분할x);
    g2.setClip(null);
    g2.setColor(Color.white);
    g2.draw(분할선);
  }

  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    int width = getImage().getWidth();
    int height = getImage().getHeight();
    if (두번째이미지 != null) {
      width = Math.max(width, 두번째이미지.getWidth());
      height = Math.max(height, 두번째이미지.getHeight());
    }
    return new Dimension(width, height);
  }
}
```
````

Comment: We need `이미지분할` code to help you.

Comment: Repeat? Do I have to write the same thing on top of it like I put in the basic image?

Comment: This time, I put it up properly